# Qual è il significato di "scattare le manette"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Il vocabolo "manette" è usato un paio di volte in [questo articolo](http://it.euronews.com/2016/12/01/tragedia-chapecoense-dopo-il-lutto-le-probabili-manette) recentemente apparso su Euronews. Si trova nel titolo

> Tragedia Chapecoense: dopo il lutto **le probabili manette**

e anche nel corpo dell'articolo

> Un paese è in lutto, ma ben presto potrebbero anche **scattare le manette** visto che stanno emergendo enormi responsabilità nell’incidente di un mezzo che non avrebbe mai dovuto decollare visto che non poteva affrontare quella distanza.

Non riesco a capire però cosa significhi "scattare le manette" in questo contesto. Ho cercato il termine "manetta" in alcuni dizionari, ma il senso dell'espressione, che immagino sia figurato, non mi è chiaro. Vuol dire che si aspettano arresti imminenti?

Comment: Forse dovrei cambiare il titolo della domanda per «Qual è il significato di "scattare le manette"?» e aggiungere la tag «idioms»... Che ne pensate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Far scattare le manette](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&ei=abBCWNheivdS9-CJKA&q=far%20scattare%20le%20manette%20&oq=far%20scattare%20le%20manette%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..41j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1.1521.3252.0.3642.11.11.0.0.0.0.160.1599.0j11.11.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..8.3.419...30i10k1.2fhM1SJSE9Y)"  è un modo di dire molto comune che significa che qualcuno verrà arrestato. L'idea è quella di un dispositivo (le manette) che scatta ossia viene  messo ai polsi della persona  da arrestare.

Entrambe le espressioni che hai evidenziato si riferiscono ad un probabile arresto.

Comment: "Scatta" in che senso?

Comment: @Charo - Scattare - 3 fig. Avere applicazione, entrare in azione: l'operazione antidroga è scattata in molte città. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scattare.shtml

Comment: O forse è piuttosto [questo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scattare/): *Prendere rapido avvio, avere inizio in modo fulmineo*.

Comment: Cioè, come ho scritto nella domanda, si aspettano probabili arresti in modo imminente.

Comment: No, direi  che il senso citato dal Sabatini Colletti è più calzante.

Comment: "Far scattare le manette"  implica un arresto ma non necessariamente imminente. Che lo sia o meno si capisce dal contesto. I link allegati alla mia risposta possono dare un'idea di come viene usata l'espressione. Nota che a queste frasi potresti sostituire a "manette" il termine "arresto."

Comment: A orecchio, vedo convivere nell'espressione “scattano le manette” lo “scattare” nel senso di “entrare in azione”, ma anche il fatto letterale che le manette si serrano attorno ai polsi dell'arrestato con un vero scatto, meccanico.

Comment: Anche secondo me il termine *scattare* in quell'espressione non ha nulla a che vedere con il chiudersi delle manette. Ci sono molte altre espressioni simili: *scattano le multe*, *scattano gli arresti*, *scattano le denuncie*... Lo *scattare* è quello di un centometrista ad inizio gara dopo lo sparo. Tipicamente quest'espressione è usata nella forma "<avviene X>, e dunque scattano le manette per ..." dove <avviene X> è di fatto il "segnale di partenza" (lo sparo) che fa "scattare" l'azione.